# Installation a secondary (Slave) DNS Server - Powerdns

Tags: domain-name-system, powerdns, slave

I want to install a secondary (slave) DNS server on a second VPS, but I don't know how. Currently I have NS! and NS2 on the same machine. I use a Powerdns and Debian 6 x64. How would I set up Powerdns on the second VPS?

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the PowerDNS [manual](http://doc.powerdns.com/) at chapter 17.